# declaring IsolatedStorage objects with different keys

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Profiles page for my app in windows phone 8
and i Need to `store data` for each Profile
so am using `IsolatedStorage`

```
IsolatedStorageSettings Profile = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

and Ofcourse a `List` for storing them all

```
List<IsolatedStorageSettings> Profiles = new List<IsolatedStorageSettings>();
```

now the problem is when i want to **Add** a profile to the List
each Profile must have a **different Key**

```
  Profile.Add("profile1", player); // "profile1" is the key of the first profile
  Profile.Save();
  Profiles.Add(Profile);
```

**so , if the user wants to add a profile I need to do** `Profile.Add("profile(CurrentIndex)",player);`

It's like:

> "player1"   "player2"   "player3" . . "playerN"

How i can write a code that does all this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `List<IsolatedStorageSettings>`, because `IsolatedStorageSettings` provides a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` that stores key-value pairs in isolated storage.

This is my code, I try it, It works well.

```
public void SavePlayer()
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings profile = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            string key = string.Format("player{0}", GetCurrentIndex());
            profile.Add(key, player);
            profile.Save();
        }

        public object GetPlayer(string Key)
        {
            object obj = null;

            IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            if (settings.Contains(Key))
            {
                obj = settings[Key];
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public int GetCurrentIndex()
        {
            int index = 1;

            IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            if (settings.Contains("CurrentIndex"))
            {
                index = (int)settings["CurrentIndex"];
                index++;
                settings["CurrentIndex"] = index;
            }
            else
            {
                settings.Add("CurrentIndex", (int)1);
            }

            settings.Save();

            return index;
        }
```

Comment: Just one more thing , why you have to initialize index everytime with "1" ?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. give an idea how to achieve what you have try.

```
public class Profile
{
public string Datakey{get; set;}
public ProfileData Data{get; set;}
}

public class ProfileData 
{
public string Name{get;set;}
//define all your profile properties
...
...

}

//Now in code


IsolatedStorageSettings ProfileSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

List<Profile> ProfileList = new List<Profile>();

//Add data in ProfileList instead of IsolatedStorageSettings 

Profile profileData = new Profile();
ProfileData data = new ProfileData ();
//Add properties
data.Name ="PlayerOne";
.....
...
profileData.Datakey="PlayerOneKey";
profileData.Data = data;
ProfileList.Add(profileData);

ProfileSettings.Add("AllProfile",ProfileList);
ProfileSettings.Save();

//If you want save another profile in IsolatedStorageSettings
 if(ProfileSettings.Contains("AllProfile"))
    {
       List<Profile> ProfileList = ProfileSettings["AllProfile"] as  List<Profile> ();
       // Add new item in profileList
    }
```